# How to determine connection error reason in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, error-handling, angularjs-http

I found that a few clients where getting errors from an Ajax request in JS.

The backend application is not getting the requests so I need to determine at which point in the connection proccess the error is occurring (for example, during the handshake). I can't reproduce this locally, so I need to get the information in JS in order to log it to a server. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Angular's $http (v1.4.7) and I only get a 0 as error status (for what I found, it means timeout). I could change the way of connecting if necessary.

Just to add info, this is a cross domain over HTTPS request, using CORS in all browsers except old IEs where I use XDomainRequest.

Comment: have you tried to look at the http response headers from the server? Assuming that you have access to google chrome developer tools or firebug.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I can't reproduce this locally. It's happening in a little less of 5% of the cases.

Comment: The error status is 0 or -1 meaning that it's not getting a response from the server.